# How to find out whether SqlCe query Has rows?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

In my simple db I use SqlCE and I cannot figure out how to correctly find out whether the query returns rows or not. `HasRows` does not work. So far I have this:

```
_DbCommand.CommandText="SELECT * FROM X"
SqlCeDataReader reader=_DbCommand.ExecuteQuery();

if (reader.FieldCount!=0) //I thought it could work (O rows - 0 fields?), but its true even with 0 rows
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `FieldCount` is the number of columns.

Comment: Yes of course, I thought it could work because I assumed with no rows there will be 0 columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
_DbCommand.CommandText="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X"
Int32 count = (Int32) _DbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
 count++;
}
if(count==0)
{
 // no rows
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible..I hoped for some easier way since reader has to know whether at least 1 record was recieved..at least that was what I thought